# How to make a C# dll/exe executable with batch?

Tags: c#, dll, cmd, exe

I wanted to make a C# dll or exe which would be usable with batch/cmd but dunno how.

If you dont know what i am on about, sometimes you can come across apps, e.g. `ReadWriteFile.exe`, which don't open when you double click 'em and the only way to use them is to open cmd and type:

ReadWriteFile.exe [options] [function] [parameters]

I think these applications are written in C++ but is there a way to do this in C# and with a dll or a exe?

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/index)

Comment: Windows distinguish between window applications (graphical user interface, using WinForms or WPF) and console applications. The language that is used to write that application is independent from that and the compiler (and maybe a runtime) is responsible to translate the source language to machine code that is understandable from the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

These are called console apps - you can create Console applications in VS

Comment: Here's an example console app : https://github.com/ChrisCarrAu/Argumentor

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can create a Console Application from the possible project types.

You can learn about this reading this [Hello World tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx).

Comment: You don't need console application to be able to read command line arguments or not create window... It's just easier that way... Side note: please don't add "thank you" text to your posts - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove for guidance.